# PHP - Checking values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare

I am trying to do something specific. I need to compare a user name and a password in each element of an array to find a match with an existing user.

There are two arrays. One containing all of the user information. And another that contains the login attempts. The exercise is to print out the user information if the login attempt is a match. So I need to compare $loginInfo to $userData to see if any of the login attempts match the stored user name and password.

I also need to use substr(), md5(), and strtolower() in this exercise. The user name is case insensitive, while the password is case sensitive. I am not sure how I am supposed to do this, but I can use strtolower() on the user name, but I am also looking for the last 8 characters in the md5 hash. Not sure how I do this either. I am comparing the last 8 characters of the password hash with the login attempt hash.

I feel like this is going to be confusing for everyone who tries to help. It is obviously confusing me.

I am attaching my code to hopefully help make more sense of this.

Thanks in advanced!

```
<?php

$userData = array();

$userData[] = array(
              'Name' => 'Joe Banks',
              'Acct' => '12345',
              'Email' => 'joe@home.com',
              'UserName' => 'Joe',
              'Password' => '8e549b63',
              'Active' => false);
              'Password' => 'Password1'
$userData[] = array(
              'Name' => 'Polly Cartwrite',
              'Acct' => '34567',
              'Email' => 'polly@yahoo.com',
              'UserName' => 'PCart',
              'Password' => '91f84e7b',
              'Active' => true);
              'Password' => '12345'
$userData[] = array(
              'Name' => 'Jake Jarvis',
              'Acct' => '81812',
              'Email' => 'jjar@gmail.com',
              'UserName' => 'jakej',
              'Password' => 'd5cc072e',
              'Active' => true);
              'Password' => 'LetMeIn'
$userData[] = array(
              'Name' => 'Kelly Williams',
              'Acct' => '76253',
              'Email' => 'kw1234@yahoo.com',
              'UserName' => 'kellyw',
              'Password' => '2d635fc7',
              'Active' => false);
              'Password' => 'Kelly'
 $userData[] = array(
              'Name' => 'Cindy Ella',
              'Acct' => '62341',
              'Email' => 'washgirl@momsplace.com',
              'UserName' => 'Cinders',
              'Password' => '87c0e367',
              'Active' => true);
              'Password' => '9Kut!5pw'

// The loginInfo array contains a series of login attempts. Each attempt
// is composed of a username and password
$loginInfo = array();
$loginInfo[] = array('joe','hello');
$loginInfo[] = array('PCART','12345');
$loginInfo[] = array('jakej','letmein');
$loginInfo[] = array('KellyW','Kelly');
$loginInfo[] = array('Cinder','9Kut!5pw');

// function printUser()
// inputs:
//   $user - an array containing the user's data. The expectation is that
//           this array will contain the user's name, password, username,
//           active status, account number and email address
// outputs:
//   n/a
// This function will print out all of the information for a particular
// user in tabular format (with the exception of the password which will
// be suppressed).
function printUser($user) {

// Each user will be printed in its own row in the table
echo "<div class='tablerow'>\n";

foreach ($user as $index => $item) {
  // suppress printing the password
  if ($index == "Password")
    continue;

  // pretty print the user's status
  if ($index == "Active")  {
    if ($item) {
      $item = "active";
    } else {
      $item = "inactive";
    }
  }

  // print the data in a tabledata box
  echo "<div class='tabledata'>$item</div>\n";
}

// end the row
echo "</div>\n";
}


function checkLogin($loginInfo){
global $userData;

foreach($userData as $attempt) {
    if($loginInfo[$attempt][0] == $userData['UserName']){
      if($loginInfo[$attempt][1] == $userData['Password']){
        printUser($userData);
      }
    }
 }
}
checkLogin($loginInfo);
?>
```

Comment: I recommend you a PHP manual to learn the basics of this language http://es.php.net/manual/es/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops to compare values of 2 arrays. Try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($loginInfo);$i++){
    foreach($userData as $attempt) {
        if($loginInfo[$i][0] == $attempt['UserName']){
            if($loginInfo[$i][1] == $attempt['Password']){
                printUser($attempt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkLogin($storage, $input){
  foreach ($storage as $data){
    if ((strtolower($data['Name']) === strtolower($input[0])) && (md5($data['Password']) === md5($input[1])))
      return true ;
  }
  return false ;
}

$user_logged = checkLogin($userData, $_POST /* Or another source */) ;

var_dump($user_logged) ;
```

I dont know why you need to compare last 8 chars of hash, but if you like, I can edit my answer.

But if you still need it, change

```
(md5($data['Password']) === md5($input['Password']))
```

to

```
(substr(md5($data['Password']), -7)) === (substr(md5($input['Password']), -7))
```

To attempt login all users:

```
$logged_users = array() ;
foreach ($loginInfo as $info){
  if (checkLogin($userData, $info){
    $logged_users[] = $info ;
  }
}

var_dump($logged_users) ;
```

Comment: I needed to point out that the 2 password fields are not actually in the code. The actual password (2nd field) is commented out and only used to show us what the password is. I don't know if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have 2 "password" fields on your user data array, the first password field appears to be the last 8 characters of the md5 hash of the second password field, if the data was provided to you this way you cant do much with it (and will have to get the hash yourself), but so long as both keys are the same the second password value will overwrite the first one.

You are correct by assuming that the strtolower function can be used to ensure the username is case insensitive, just use it on both the attempt username and the username of the user data when comparing them

```
strtolower($loginInfo[$attempt][0]) === strtolower($userData['UserName'])
```

The md5 will be used to get the hash of the password so that you can use it for whatever reason you need, like

```
$hash = md5($loginInfo[$attempt][1];
```

The substr will help you get the last 8 chars of the md5 hash, the function is used like so:

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Dont want to ruin all your homework for you, but check http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php, youll find your answer on the negative start examples.